# Why don't we use the definite article in "you have the experience of..."?

Tags: definite-article, zero-article, uncountable-nouns

Consider these examples:

> 1. Do you have **the** experience of working with kids?
> 2. Do you have experience of working with kids?

From what I have learned, we can use "the" with uncountable nouns when we are referring to something specific:

- I like **the** confidence **of** Luisa. (not I like confidence of Luisa)
- That's **the** beauty **of** this place. (not That's beauty of this place)

Now, shouldn't we use the first example: "Do you have the experience of working with kids?"?

Why is the second example: "Do you have experience of working with kids?" even correct? And why is the first example incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

But the specificity (or lack of it) is exactly the point. The question isn't asking if you have a specific instance of experience with kids. It's asking whether you have *any* experience.

The only time the article would be appropriate with "experience" in this way is if you are asking about a specific memorable experience. You might say:

> Have you had the experience of working with Henry?

if Henry is a particularly difficult customer, for example.

Comment: In fact, it's syntactically valid (if unlikely) to include the article in *Do you have **the** experience of working with kids*, but this doesn't refer to ***a specific INSTANCE*** of so doing. It's singling out "working with kids" and asking about ***that one specific KIND of experience***.

Comment: +1 Really a helpful answer. In your Henry example, can I rephrase it as: "Did you have the experience of working with Henry?"?